# Mysql : Dump/Exports existing data to a .sql file

Tags: mysql, database, dump

I have a database. All I want to do is dump ALL the existing data in every table to I can then use it to simply import the SQL to my new database?

Im presuming the dump will be a bunch of MySQL `INSERT` statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), native mysql tool for this purpose.

Comment: Example: `mysqldump -u username -p db_name > dump.sql`

Comment: -p stands for password :) without a space :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool such as [mysql workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) or [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) to create the dump.
It will be a bunch of inserts as well as all the other data in it (such as procedures).